# Actions with completion blocks Animation(Plist)

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

Having trouble to play animations with completion

On touch, Happy animation should play -
when animation is complete it should return to idle animation 
(but nothing happens after happy animation is complete)

```
  if ([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"myMonster"]) {

        id callHappy= [SKAction performSelector:@selector (playHappy) onTarget:self];
        id callIdle = [SKAction performSelector:@selector (ReturnToIdleAnimation) onTarget:self];
        NSArray *actionsequence = @[callHappy,callIdle];
        SKAction *allActions= [SKAction sequence:actionsequence];

        [myMonster runAction:allActions completion:^{
        NSLog(@"myMonster Action Complete");
       // [self ReturnToIdleAnimation];

        //*** [self PlayIdleAnimation];*** works
        // but am interested as to why is doesn't get called on the main game layer???


        }];
    }
}

-(void)ReturnToIdleAnimation
{
    [myMonster removeAllActions];
     NSLog(@"ReturnToIdleAnimation");
     [myMonster PlayIdleAnimation];
}

-(void)playHappy
{
     NSLog(@"playHappyAnimation");
     [myMonster PlayHappyAnimation];
}
```

///

```
logs  PlayHappyAnimation
      animation with completion finished
```

//In monsterClass.m

```
    -(void)PlayAnimationNamed:(NSString*)string looping:(BOOL)isLooping
{
    //remove actions on sprite
    [self removeAllActions];

    //check if looping
    if (isLooping==YES) {
        self->animationAction = [self animationFromPlist:string];
        id repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:animationAction];
        [self runAction:repeat];
    }

     else if (isLooping==NO)
    {
      self->animationAction = [self animationFromPlist:string];
      SKAction* actionOnce = [SKAction sequence:@[animationAction]];

      [self runAction:actionOnce completion:^ {
      //when finished return to idle loop here
      NSLog(@"animation with completion finished");
      }];
     }
}

-(void)PlayIdleAnimation
{
    [self    PlayAnimationNamed:@"Monster_IdleAnimation_plist"looping:YES];
    NSLog(@"PlayIdleAnimation");
}
-(void)PlayHappyAnimation
{
    [self PlayAnimationNamed:@"Monster_Happy_Animation_plist"looping:NO];
     NSLog(@"PlayHappyAnimation");
}
```

Comment: um we must me missing info, your logs are not consistent with your code,  you really should be showing everything related to this question, like what are your SKActions being used